# Solve the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

The recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1$ has the solution $T(n) = O(2^n)$. show that a substitution proof fails with the assumption $T(n) <= c2^n$, where $c>0$.
Then show how to subtract a lower-order term to make a substitution proof work.

This is question 4.3-3 of Introduction to Algorithms.

Using substitution, I'm getting -
$T(n) \le c2^n + 1$
Because of $+1$, this is failing.

Now, if I use a constant d as a lower-order term, I get
$T(n) \le c2^n -d$

Substituting this, we get
$T(n) \le c2^n -2d + 1$

I cannot prove this time complexity with substitution by taking any lower-order term.

Comment: You assumed $T(n-1) \le c2^{n-1}-d$ and hoped to prove $T(n) \le c2^n-d$. For now you only reached $T(n)\le c2^n - 2d+1$. If you pick $d$ that satisfies $-2d+1 \le -d$, then you will reach your goal.

Comment: -2d+1 will always be less than -d, for all d>1. So, can we prove it like this - since -2d+1 < -d. Therefore T(n) <= c2^n - d

Comment: OK, then if you assume (for example) $T(n-1) \le c2^{n-1}-2$, then you should be able to prove the induction step result $T(n) \le c2^n - 2$.

Comment: Note that $T_n + 1 = 2(T_{n-1} + 1)$

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. Here we finish off your proof of the bound. We assume that $ T(n) \leq c2^n - d $ for some constants $c,d$ and substitute:

$$ T(n) \leq 2 \left( c2^{n - 1} - d \right) + 1 $$
$$ \leq  c2^n - 2d + 1 $$
$$ \leq  c2^n - d $$

which holds when $d \geq 1$. And so we conclude $T(n) \leq c2^n - d = O(2^n)$. Note that if $T(1) = 1$ then it can be shown that $T(n) = 2^n - 1$.